# Create a new scheduled Tweet via the API

Tags: api, twitter

I looked into their documentation and they do provide this feature:

https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170532-scheduled-tweets#How_to_create_a_new_scheduled_Tweet

But would it be possible to do this through the API (I didn't find any reference to this or attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it with the Twitter API.  You have two choices:

1. Either tell your code to run at a specific time (using cron or similar), or check what the time is before posting.
2. Use a third party service like Buffer - https://bufferapp.com/developers/api

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using  Twitter Ads API(scheduled tweets api).

From the api doc,

> Scheduled Tweets allow an advertiser or user to create a Tweet that can be scheduled to go live at a later date. In addition to being able create and manage these Tweets, the API allows the ability to associate these Tweets with a line item, to be promoted once the Tweet goes live. This allows advertisers to stage create native Tweets and plan their campaign creatives in advance of any key initiatives. For example, staging a Tweet creative to live immediately upon a new product announcement.
>
> The full set of functionality provided by the Scheduled Tweets API endpoints are listed below:
>
> - Create, modify and view newly scheduled Tweets
> - Associate a Scheduled Tweet with a line item
> - Query and manage existing scheduled Tweets
> - Once a Scheduled Tweet goes live, retrieve the live Tweet id

Complete details can be found [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/creatives/guides/scheduled-tweets-guide)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Scheduled Tweet for the account's full promotable user (default) or the user specified in the as_user_id parameter.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/creatives/api-reference/scheduled-tweets#post-accounts-account-id-scheduled-tweets

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 5 user per account... even with a developer account you have to request acces to that API.